# Next js standalone mood not optimizing images?

Tags: next.js, sharp, nextjs-image

I am create a next build with standalone output. I follow this answer- [How to deploy NextJs (SSR) using "Output File Tracing" feature to Azure App Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73725010/how-to-deploy-nextjs-ssr-using-output-file-tracing-feature-to-azure-app-serv)

After setting up I run my server like this `node server.js`

It works perfectly. But here image optimization not working. I found one error-

`Error: 'sharp' is required to be installed in standalone mode for the image optimization to function correctly`

I recheck package.json and I can see sharp is already installed. Then I add this to my `.env` file-
`NEXT_SHARP_PATH=/tmp/node_modules/sharp`

But not working. Please any help me. I need image opmization feature in standalone mood.

***Note: I use linux subsystem on windows. In linux subsystem, When I run production mode `npm run start`. Image optmization automatically work in this mode, I haven't to give `.env` also. When I start my project in standalone mood, image optimization is not working. Even when I give `.env` it's not working.

Here is my next.config.js-

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const withPWA = require("next-pwa")({
  dest: "public",
  register: true,
  disable: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
});

const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
  output: "standalone",
  images: {
    minimumCacheTTL: 2592000,
    domains: ["dzzoo94ozikw5.cloudfront.net", "lh3.googleusercontent.com", "platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com"]
  },
}
```

module.exports = withPWA(nextConfig)

Answer (score 0):

```
yarn add sharp
```

or

```
npm install sharp
```

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/sharp-missing-in-production